# JavaFX window resizing when running the application on two different sized screens

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have created a JavaFX window on my laptop using scene builder..however when i try to run the same on a workstation with a larger screen the JavaFX application does not resize itself and is displayed towards the left top of the screen..is there any way by which I can have the application window to be resized as and when the laptop/workstation screen size varies?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your JavaFX application you can maximize the `Stage` window using `.setMaximized(true)`. This will make it "fill the screen" no matter what the screensize is. Be sure to use a layout that resizes well with different screen sizes if you do this.

To get the `Stage`, you can call `.getWindow()` on the `Scene` and cast it to the `Stage` it is. Here is an example using a `Node node` I have access to in my application:

`((Stage) node.getScene().getWindow()).setMaximized(true)`

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a ratio. Determine what you want the height ratio and width ratio to be. Then get the width and height of the screen and apply the ratio.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication287 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        double heightRatio = .25;
        double widthRatio = .30;

        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

        double sceneHeight = primaryScreenBounds.getHeight() * heightRatio;
        double sceneWidth = primaryScreenBounds.getWidth() * widthRatio;

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```